# Removing decomissioned cassandra node

Tags: cassandra

Quick question. I've decomissioned cassandra node and my current ring status is this:

```
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns    Token                                       
                                                                               164601615634248514846538874370590613562     
10.xx.xx.95   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  133.54 GB       51.10%  81394124714323148288828865376976834962      
10.xx.xx.237   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  118.17 GB       26.10%  125797595970943604911023643819769152073     
10.xx.xx.238   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  117.52 GB       13.03%  147966787611381868042912949356409642178     
10.xx.xx.159  datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  117.49 GB       6.52%   159068473488869428966656950048578700872     
10.xx.xx.185  datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  117.47 GB       3.25%   164601615634248514846538874370590613562
```

The decomissioned node is the first 'empty' row. How do I get rid of it? There's removetoken command but one of the live machines now has the same token like the decomissioned one. Is it safe to run the command:

```
nodetool -h localhost removetoken 164601615634248514846538874370590613562
```

?

I am unsure what this command will actually remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misreading the output. The empty row is just a convenience row to make it easier to see the token range of the first node. It is simply showing you the token of the last node in the ring. In your example the empty row's token is the same as node `10.xx.xx.185`, which is live.